# List the top 3 countries with the highest suicides for each year

Tags: python, pandas

I want to list down the top three countries with the highest suicides for each year from 1985-2016.
Now i know how to list down all the countries for each year. Just don't know how to only fetch top 3 with the highest suicides number.

```
df.groupby(['year','country']).suicides_no.sum()
```

I have written the above code but it lists all the countries not just top 3.

Answer (score 2):

If need only 3 countries per all years use:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.random.randint(1985, 2017, size=N),
                   'country':np.random.choice([f'country{i}' for i in range(20)], size=N),
                   'suicides_no':np.random.randint(100, size=N)})


print(df)
    year    country  suicides_no
0   2015  country17           54
1   1998  country12           73
2   2015  country18           81
3   1987  country17           62
4   2013   country1           67
..   ...        ...          ...
95  2008  country14           80
96  2010  country13           84
97  2003   country3           90
98  2005  country18            4
99  2009  country14           21

[100 rows x 3 columns]

s = df.groupby(['year','country']).suicides_no.sum().nlargest(3)
print (s)
year  country  
1995  country13    196
1999  country6     165
1986  country7     144
Name: suicides_no, dtype: int32
```

If need only 3 countries per each year use:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['year','country']).suicides_no.sum()
         .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
         .nlargest(3))
print (df1)
year  country  
1985  country9     108
      country19     99
      country17     69
1986  country7     144
      country18     80

2014  country15     48
2015  country18     81
      country12     79
      country17     54
2016  country1      61
Name: suicides_no, Length: 78, dtype: int32
```

---

```
N = 3
df1 = (df.groupby(['year','country']).suicides_no.sum()
         .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)
         .nlargest(N)
         .reset_index(name=f'top{N}'))
print (df1)
    year    country  top3
0   1985   country9   108
1   1985  country19    99
2   1985  country17    69
3   1986   country7   144
4   1986  country18    80
..   ...        ...   ...
73  2014  country15    48
74  2015  country18    81
75  2015  country12    79
76  2015  country17    54
77  2016   country1    61

[78 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The latter is the one i needed. You are genius.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nlargest()` from pandas. For example, `df.groupby(['year', 'country'])['suicides_no'].sum().groupby(level='year').nlargest(3)` could be helpful.